# How to notify android app when device is connected with USB port

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to count how many times mobile has connected with USB port. But I don't want to count when the device is connected with USB port only for charging the phone. Is there any way to do that in Flutter or Java?

Comment: I think you should look into android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED intent: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host

Answer (score 0):

There is one broadcast event and if you turned on `Debug` in your `application settings` then you will see a bug on your notification bar when you plugged USB

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String str = intent.getAction();
    if (str.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_STATE)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        usbConnected = extras.getBoolean(UsbManager.USB_CONNECTED);
        ...
        ...
```